# Deploy Application Pages

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, layouts

I have added a new page to my project and now I need to deploy it.

When I deploy with visual studio it places the page in:
\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\AutomatisationDesActesRemises

- The page is inside a Layout folder that I created from the visual studio SharePoint mapped folder.

Question:

When crating a WSP file,
the best way is ...

It is imperative to create a Module to deploy that page?
Or it will be placed in the correct folder because it is inside a Mapped Layout Folder ?

Thank you for your answers ....

Juliano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no needs to add a module if you place it inside a Mapped Layout Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, modules deploy files to the content database. Files deployed to the LAYOUTS virtual directory do not exist in the content database at all.